# Is social security paid biweekly or monthly?

Tags: united-states, retirement, social-security

Is social security paid biweekly or monthly? My father is retiring soon and I can't seem to find this answered directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Social Security is paid on a monthly basis. From the [program's website](https://www.ssa.gov/kc/rp_paybenefits.htm):

### SSI (Supplemental Security Income) Benefits

> SSI benefits are paid of the 1st of the month. Unless the 1st falls on the weekend then the payments will be issued the Friday before the 1st.

Your father will only get these if he is eligible for them.

### RSDI (Retirement, Survivors and Disability) also referred to as SSA Benefits

> Since June 1997 SSA delivers recurring RSDI benefits on four days throughout the month on the 3rd of the month and on the second, third and fourth Wednesdays of the month.

People who got benefits before June 1997 get it on the 3rd of the month, so that wouldn't apply to your father. Instead, he would get his benefits depending on the day of the month that he was born:

- 1st – 10th: Second Wednesday of the month
- 11th – 20th: Third Wednesday of the month
- 21st – 31st: Fourth Wednesday of the month

Comment: I get SS disability. I have been getting it for about 5 years. I get it on the 3rd of the month or the previous business day if the 3rd falls on a weekend or holiday.